# JavaScript: Change text color depending on video.currentTime

Tags: javascript, video, timestamp, controls

I have created navigation buttons for my video, some sort of timestamps that allow a user to jump to a certain moment in the video on click. The buttons change their color whenever they are clicked and the value of video.currentTime is in a particular range. When one button is red, the rest must be white ofcourse.

Take a look at my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRZPEP

My solution does work. However, I feel like it's too complicated and the feature could be done much simpler and with less code.

The important bit of javascript is under the //VIDEO NAV BUTTON FUNCTION header. 
I'm just wondering if there's any way I could get rid of the changeToWhite() function? For example, by using some method making the button red only when the video.currentTime finds itself within a particular range?

```
var DOMstrings = {

nav_btn: document.querySelector('.navbar-button'),
nav_btn_mobile: document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler'), 
nav_list: document.querySelector('#wrapper-for-list'), 
//video
video: document.querySelector('#myVideo'), 
//video-nav-buttons
nav_btn_1: document.querySelector('.video-nav h1:nth-child(1)'),
nav_btn_2: document.querySelector('.video-nav h1:nth-child(2)'), 
nav_btn_3: document.querySelector('.video-nav h1:nth-child(3)'), 
nav_btn_4: document.querySelector('.video-nav h1:nth-child(4)'), 
nav_btn_5: document.querySelector('.video-nav h1:nth-child(5)')
```

}

//VIDEO NAV BUTTON FUNCTION

```
var navigateVideo = function() {

    var video_nav = [DOMstrings.nav_btn_1, DOMstrings.nav_btn_2, DOMstrings.nav_btn_3, DOMstrings.nav_btn_4, DOMstrings.nav_btn_5]

    var setTime = function(time) {

        DOMstrings.video.currentTime = time;
    };

    var changeToWhite = function() {

        video_nav.forEach(function(cur) {

            cur.style.color = "white";
        });
    };

    DOMstrings.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {

        var cur = DOMstrings.video.currentTime;

        if (cur >= 0 && cur < 5) {
            changeToWhite();
            DOMstrings.nav_btn_1.style.color = "red";
        } else if (cur > 5 && cur < 10) {
            changeToWhite();
            DOMstrings.nav_btn_2.style.color = "red";
        } else if (cur > 10 && cur < 15) {
            changeToWhite();
            DOMstrings.nav_btn_3.style.color = "red";
        } else if (cur > 15 && cur < 20) {
            changeToWhite();
            DOMstrings.nav_btn_4.style.color = "red";
        } else if (cur > 25) {
            changeToWhite();
            DOMstrings.nav_btn_5.style.color = "red";
        } 

    });

    DOMstrings.nav_btn_1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setTime(0);
        changeToWhite();
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
    DOMstrings.nav_btn_2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setTime(15);
        changeToWhite();
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
    DOMstrings.nav_btn_3.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setTime(30);
        changeToWhite();
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
    DOMstrings.nav_btn_4.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setTime(45);
        changeToWhite();
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
    DOMstrings.nav_btn_5.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        setTime(60);
        changeToWhite();
        e.target.style.color = "red";
    });
};
```

Comment: I don't see the buttons in the pen

Comment: I'm sorry, here is the right link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRZPEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this a little by renaming `changeToWhite()` to `changeToRed(button)`:

```
const changeToRed = (button) => {
  video_nav.forEach(cur => {
    button.style.color = (cur === button) ? 'red' : 'white';
  })
}
```

Then pass in each button when you call it:

```
changeToRed(DOMstrings.nav_btn_1);

// Previously:
// changeToWhite();
// DOMstrings.nav_btn_1.style.color = "red";
```

A few other things: You could make a single function that takes in a time in seconds instead of repeating the same function 5 times:

```
function handleClick(seconds) {
  return function(e) {
    setTime(seconds);
    changeToRed(e.target);
  }
}

DOMstrings.nav_btn_1.addEventListener('click', handleClick(0));
DOMstrings.nav_btn_2.addEventListener('click', handleClick(15));
DOMstrings.nav_btn_3.addEventListener('click', handleClick(30));
...etc
```

You could also get rid of the if/else block by doing this instead:

```
const cur = DOMstrings.video.currentTime;
// Divide the current time by 5 and round down, so 0-4 seconds
// would use index 0 (nav_btn_1), 5-9 seconds would use index
// 1 (nav_btn_2), etc
const buttonIndex = Math.floor(cur / 5);
changeToRed(video_nav[buttonIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate logic in the timeUpdate listener, and you could also eliminate much repetition in the click listeners by replacing them all with a single click listener on the buttons' parent element. (This works because of event bubbling.) Altogether, it might look something like:

```
// Selectors
const video = document.querySelector("#myVideo");
const videoNav = document.querySelector(".video-nav");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".video-nav button");

//Bindings
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateTime);
videoNav.addEventListener("click", conditionallySetTime);


//Listeners

function updateTime(event){
  const time = event.target.time;
  buttons.forEach(function(button, index){
    button.style.color = index == Math.floor(time/15) ? "red" : "white"
  });
}

function conditionallySetTime(event){
  if(event.target.tagName == button){ // Now we care about this click
    buttons.forEach(function(button, index){
      if(event.target == button){
        button.style.color = "red";
        setTime(index * 15); // If 1st button is 0, 2nd is 15, etc.
      }
      else { 
        button.style.color = "white";
      }
    }
  }
}
```